# How to dynamically use Concat to remove null lists

Tags: c#, json

I am passing lists of the same type to a json file but as well all no if json finds a node it expects data in it I am having a problem where I am using the `concat` function but the lists will not always have assess in them so I need to no a way to be able to build the lists up dynamically.

```
 List<Asset> AllAssets = allAssets.Concat(_vheiclesList)
                                .Concat(_propertyList)
                                .Concat(_securedLoansAssets)
                                .Concat(_allSavings)
                                .Concat(_allPensions)
                                .Concat(_allOtherAssets)
                                .ToList();
```

For example if there was no properties or savings then the list join would read like this.

```
List<Asset> AllAssets = allAssets.Concat(_vheiclesList)
                                .Concat(_securedLoansAssets)
                                .Concat(_allPensions)
                                .Concat(_allOtherAssets)
                                .ToList();
```

Each one of the lists is of type `asset` and then I also need to be able to tell the json to remove these so I need a way of adding each one via an if statement to check if `null` then don't concat it.

Comment: I have stated what the problem is i stated that a list may not always have values ie be null !

Comment: Ah I stand corrected ... you are correct sir ... it's early, I need more coffee and I was too hasty. Your question is fine - my apologies rogue. Sigh can you do a minor edit so I can remove my down vote --- seems SO won't allow it to be changed till you do.

Comment: @rboe thank you for edit ... resolved now

Comment: @henners66 dont worry about it im from belfast so a early riser ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by constructing an array of arrays, then filtering out the null arrays(Where), then flattening the remaining arrays back into a single array (SelectMany).

```
List<Asset> AllAssets = new[]
    {
        allAssets,
        _vheiclesList,
        _propertyList,
        _securedLoanAssets,
        _allSavings,
        _allPensions,
        _allOtherAssets,
    }
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: that is very nice i would have hoped contact would have been smart enough to do this its self like but it didnt appear to do so

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension method that handles the `null` value for a list. E.g.

```
    public static class EnumerableExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
        {
            if (second == null)
                return first;
            return first.Concat(second);
        }
    }
```

Then you can rewrite your statement to

```
List<Asset> AllAssets = allAssets.ConcatOrDefault(_vheiclesList)
                            .ConcatOrDefault(_propertyList)
                            .ConcatOrDefault(_securedLoansAssets)
                            .ConcatOrDefault(_allSavings)
                            .ConcatOrDefault(_allPensions)
                            .ConcatOrDefault(_allOtherAssets)
                            .ToList();
```

Now values like `_propertyList` or `_allSavings` may be null. In this case just the unaltered sequence is returned.

Comment: That is very sweet rboe i persume i just implmenet in the satic class as usual as you have in when you say contact or default will that still inlcude it in the string ? .

Answer (score 0):

The minimal change solution is probably to use the null coalescing operator:

```
List<Asset> AllAssets = allAssets
    .Concat(_vheiclesList ?? Enumerable.Empty<Asset>())
    .Concat(_propertyList ?? Enumerable.Empty<Asset>())
    .Concat(_securedLoansAssets ?? Enumerable.Empty<Asset>())
    .Concat(_allSavings ?? Enumerable.Empty<Asset>())
    .Concat(_allPensions ?? Enumerable.Empty<Asset>())
    .Concat(_allOtherAssets ?? Enumerable.Empty<Asset>())
    .ToList();
```